# Android Hilt Unresolved reference @Inject in Arctic Fox

Tags: android, android-studio, dagger-hilt

After upgrade to Arctic Fox, @Inject suddenly missing... but still able to build the project.

[Unresolved reference @Inject IDE hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQpWo.png)

dependencies

```
AGP '7.1.0-alpha02'
hilt_version '2.37'
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this once, this is for a similar issue and worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70616657/9895306